# PHP, SEO, special characters in URL

Tags: php, url, web, seo

I'm trying to create search engine with static URL addresses containing parameters. For example: www.domain.com/search,city,region,type.html

For some reason (database relations are not well projected) I can't place identificators in URL - I have put names of parameters exactly as they are. The problem is that parameters can contain special characters like "ó", "ż", "ć", "ą". I've read that putting this into URL is not recommended in terms of SEO so I'm not going to do that because SEO is very important for me. Only parameter named  city will have special signs.

I have some ideas.

1. After special character add another special character like "-" that tells the script that single character before should be replace, eg. www.domain.com/search,bial-ystok,wielkopolskie,restaurant.html.
2. Put some another parameter at end of URL e.g. www.domain.com/search,bialystok,wielkopolskie,restaurant,4.html that tells the script that sign 4 in parameter city should be replace.

Which way is the best? Any other ideas? URL should be nice lookin'.

Comment: Another way: use Google API to find proper name of city with parametr without special sings. :) Thanks, you are very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the above solution is right, at least not from my point of view.
What you have to do, or at least what i would do is:
1) Have a table for countries, one for states and one for cities. I assume you already have that, if you don't, then use a Open Source CMS, like Open Cart, and take them from there, or use a webservice like geonames.org.
2) Each table will have a column named slug/nice_url/whatever where you will store the nice url replica of your actual name. You will use: https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify which is a great php library to create nice slugs.
3) Then, all you have to do is to index the slug column in each table, then your urls will become something like:
`www.domain.com/search/bialystok/wielkopolskie/restaurant` and based on that, you know that `wielkopolskie` is the name of your city, you will search it in your city table using the slug and you will get the right record.

Note 1: in my example i don't really know if i got the right city as i don't know the cities from your country, but you should get the point.
Note 2: i know this means a lot of work and changes in your end, but if you do it, at least do it right, it will be a win in the long run.
Note 3: maybe a reading into relational databases will also help you in creating your tables in a relational manner.

Comment: I agree. This is right way, but I can't do that because of too much work.

Comment: I'm afraid you may spend much more time supporting the not-right solution, and the final effects will still be not perfect. Try it - maybe it will not be so much work?

Comment: And about cities, "wielkopolskie" is voivodeship (a province), and the "Białystok" is the city. So the URL might rather look like `/search/wielkopolskie/bialystok/restaurant`. And I would say that this kind of URL _is_ SEO (and user) friendly, while the ones presented in the question probably are not so much.